# Divide a Stack Panel in 3 Equal Sizes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make an row with a **left groupbox (docked to the left), an image in the center and a right groupbox (docked to the right).**

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong but it compiles like this: [My WPF Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95ZtH.png)

I tried to use ColumnDefinitions without sucess.. Help me please

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <GroupBox x:Name="RightGroupBox" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#515151" BorderThickness="1" Header="Right Tools" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Width="369" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ToolsStackRight" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,-2,0">
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool10" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool5_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool9" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool4_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool8" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool3_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool7" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool2_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool6" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool1_SelectionChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Name="ToolsImageLeft" Height="256" Width="294" Source="/AMOB_CNC;component/Resources/5tolls_3d.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="40,0,0,0"></Image>

    <GroupBox x:Name="LeftGroupBox" Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="#515151" BorderThickness="1" Header="Right Tools" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Width="369" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ToolStackLeft" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,-2,0" >
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool5" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool5_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool4" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool4_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool3" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool3_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool2" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool2_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool1" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool1_SelectionChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: remove `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >` and last `</StackPanel>`

Comment: A little better but still something not working https://gyazo.com/32ec21a2db5a315330c9986067face59

Comment: @ASh please help me

Answer (score 1):

StackPanel inside Grid messed the layout. Remove it and fix Grid.Column numbers on elements (numbers start from 0)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GroupBox x:Name="RightGroupBox" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#515151" BorderThickness="1" Header="Right Tools" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Width="369" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ToolsStackRight" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,-2,0">
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool10" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool5_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool9" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool4_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool8" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool3_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool7" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool2_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool6" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool1_SelectionChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Name="ToolsImageLeft" Height="256" Width="294" Source="/AMOB_CNC;component/Resources/5tolls_3d.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="40,0,0,0"></Image>

    <GroupBox x:Name="LeftGroupBox" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="#515151" BorderThickness="1" Header="Right Tools" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Width="369" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ToolStackLeft" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,-2,0" >
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool5" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool5_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool4" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool4_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool3" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool3_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool2" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool2_SelectionChanged"/>
            <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool1" Width="300" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool1_SelectionChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. You are a genious ;)

Comment: I approve ur reply when I can

Comment: do you know how I can expand the groupboxes? Basically fill the remain space

Comment: An alternative would be a UniformGrid with rows=1, columns=3 - then you do not need the column definitions & the three controls will be automatically placed in the correct column without needing to specify the column.

Comment: @qweqeqwe, remove `Width="369"` from groupboxes and they will stretch